# Changing file permissions and adding owner from CMD

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, windows-command-prompt

I am unable to change permissions of certain files in a directory even though I have logged into a server using an Administrator account.

Is there a way to force the permissions of these files via CMD recursively?

Answer (score 1):

You can take ownership of these files using the command line tool Takeown https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx

> Enables an administrator to recover access to a file that previously
>   was denied, by making the administrator the owner of the file.

You can then apply the required permissions using Icacls https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx

> Displays or modifies discretionary access control lists (DACLs) on
>   specified files, and applies stored DACLs to files in specified
>   directories.

Comment: also make sure you are running with UAC elevation. You would not have admin privileges otherwise.